# Wo kommt das "Muckaseckele" (auch "Muggaseggele") im Schwäbischen her?

Tags: etymology, swabian

Im Schwäbischen gibt es den Ausdruck *a Muckaseckele* für "ein ganz kleines bisschen". Ich habe es bisher vor allem bei Handwerkern und Bauleuten gehört, zum Beispiel, wenn es darum geht, den Balken eines Fachwerks noch ein ganz kleines bisschen (eben *a Muckaseckele*) zu verschieben.

Ich erkläre mir das Wort als "ein Mückensäckchen", aber was das sein soll, ist mir trotzdem schleierhaft. Ich dachte immer an den (anzunehmenderweise ja recht kleinen) Hodensack einer Mücke oder vielmehr Fliege (*Mucka* sind eher Fliegen, denn Mücken wären *Schnooka*), aber das ist natürlich jetzt sehr volksetymologisch. (Und biologisch vermutlich auch nicht haltbar.)

Wer weiß mehr?

Vielleicht noch eine Überlegung: Die Deutung als "Mückensäckchen" ist ja allzu naheliegend (und wie man aus ersten Anworten sieht, auch überaus populär). Ich fände es aber interessant, auch anderen möglichen Entstehungswegen nachzuspüren. Könnte es sich zum Beispiel um ein Wort handeln, das - wie etliche andere - einen missverstandenen und verballhornten französischen Ausdruck zur Wurzel hat? Vielleicht etwas, das in Handwerkskreisen einmal als kleine Maßeinheit verwendet wurde?

Oder hat das Wort eine literarische, keine alltagssprachliche Wurzel? In irgend einem historischen Schelmenroman oder einem Schwank?

---

<sub>Anmerkung zur Aussprache: In der mir vertrauteren Region (Oberschwaben) sowie bei den von mir beobachteten Sprecherindividuen höre ich es mit einem fürs Schwäbischen relativ scharfen k/g, darum notiere ich hier "Muckaseckele". Doch ist natürlich auch Schreibung als "Muggaseggele" möglich, speziell in Gegenden wo (oder bei Individuen für die) weichere Aussprache üblich sein mag. Für die von mir beobachteten Fälle würde ich jedoch unterscheiden zwischen dem weichen g wie in *Seggl* (Idiot, Dummkopf - *Du bisch a Seggl*!) und dem nicht ganz so weichen k (oder "harten g") wie in *Säckle* (Säckchen). Ich kann mich aber auch täuschen. Vielleicht ist meine akustische Wahrnehmung durch die Schreibung in Standard-Deutsch getrübt.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muggeseggele) weiß mehr, wenn man eine üblichere schwäbische Schreibweise zugrunde legt:

> Muggeseggele (auch Muggaseggele, Muggaseggel oder Muggaseggl)

Demnach ist die Vermutung tatsächlich zutreffend, dass sich der Begriff auf das Geschlechtsorgan der männlichen Stubenfliege bezieht. Ein Forscher hat dieses sogar vermessen und kommt auf einen Durchschnittswert von 0,22 mm.

Das "Seggele" wiederum geht auf den lateinischen Ausdruck *saccellus*, sprich den Hodensack zurück.

Comment: Der Hinweis auf *saccellus* ist auf jeden Fall hilfreich, da solide. Der Rest ist auch interessant, aber wenn man sehr gründlich sein will, könnte man den zitierten Wikipedia-Artikel als *chiefly opinion based* geißeln. Er wiederholt die (naheliegende) These, dass das Geschlechtsorgan des Stubenfliegerichs referenziert wird, doch einen echten Beleg bringt er m. E. nicht. Ich bin den genannten Quellen nicht weiter nachgegangen, aber es sieht so aus, as würde hier im Kreise zitiert. Was mir fehlt, ist ein stichhaltiger Hinweis auf Entstehung des Ausdrucks, vielleicht mit frühen Nennungen.

Answer (score 1):

#### Muckeseckele

Unzweifelhaft entspricht der erste Teil dieses zusammengesetzten Wortes einer Mücke oder auch Fliege (im schwäbischen Muck genannt), in jedem Fall aber einem kleinen Insekt.

Beim zweiten Wortteil besteht Unsicherheit, da der *Seggel* im Schwäbischen zwar selten auch die Bedeutung eines *Säckchens* hatte, gleichwohl aber viel häufiger in der Bedeutung des *männlichen Hodensacks* gefunden wird und ein kleines Säckchen würde *Säckle* genannt werden.

Dennoch und eben weil die Aussprache des `k` für Schwäbisch relativ hart ist, denke ich, dass hier die ganz ursprüngliche Bedeutung des [Seckels](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS23244#XGS23244) im Diminutiv gemeint ist; ein mittlerweile ausgestorbener Begriff für die Geldbörse. Das kommt auch der Bedeutung des Muckenseckele als etwas von vernachlässigbar geringem Wert am nächsten:

> ein Muckenseckele ist nämlich die kleine Geldbörse einer Fliege.

Comment: Dieser Erklärungsversuch gefällt mir gut wegen seiner Alltagsnähe. Es war ja bis ins 19. Jhd. (oder sogar darüber hinaus?) üblich, Geld, wenn man welches hatte, in einem kleinen Beutel am Gürtel oder Hals mit sich herumzutragen, nicht wie heute in komplizierten Produkten des Kürschnerhandswerks, für die man wieder eine extra Tasche braucht, und diese *Säckle* waren also omnipräsent. Außerdem scheint es mir im dorfschwäbischen Alltag bei aller Viehverbundenheit sehr ungebräuchlich, Geschlechtsorgane welchen Wesens auch immer explizit zu erwähnen, was die Fliegenhodentheorie weiter schwächt..

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Danke. Ganz so artig gings aber auch wieder nicht zu, denn mit dem schwäbischen *Seggel* ist schon ein Hodensack gemeint ... und ein *Muggeschiss* oder ein *Hennefiddle* sind auch recht derb.

Comment: Der oben genannte Wikipedia-Artikel verweist hierzu darauf, dass "der „Seckel“ [...] eines der wenigen explizit sexuell konnotierten Schimpfwörter in der deutschen Sprache" sei und nennt als Quelle auch ein Buch, dessen tatsächlicher Inhalt leider nicht bekannt ist.

Comment: @Takkat   Ja, das *Fiedla* wird häufig auch im Alltag benützt. Ich würde es aber nicht zu den eigentlichen Sexualorganen zählen.